# Mount container folders to hosts

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, microservices, minio

I have three containers implemented as follows:

[image: docker container]

Each container is a Django project that has a folder called `images` that holds the files (gray rectangles).

I want to access the images of each container in the following format through the website address:

> `http://example.com/storage/<container>/images/<file name>`

**What I tried?**

I created a `storage` folder on the host. Then I considered a separate folder for each container. Finally, I mounted each of these folders to their containers. But images are not available from the website.

```
/storage/
        /users/images/...
        /company/images/...
        /financial/images/...
```

Can anyone help?

#### UPDATED

```
# Create Volume
docker volume create users

# mount
docker run -v users:storage/users/images user-image
```

Comment: Can you provide the commands you used?

Comment: Is there another solution that can I get images? Is the way I used correct?

Comment: The high-level description sounds like you're looking for a reverse proxy that can forward HTTP requests to `/user/images` to the `/images` path on the user service.  You don't need that proxy to store anything and then you don't need to share files.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze . A series of images are stored in the user's container and I do not have direct access to them through the host. But I do not know how to send them to the client(their urls). How can I access them through my website address? ( Images are protected and should not be accessed directly by the user without authentication)

Comment: How do you forward other requests to the individual services, for example their REST API calls?  Do the same for your images.

Comment: @DavidMaze First, nginx receives the <get image> request and sends it to the company service. The image is stored in the user service. The company service sends the request to the user service through REST. (All requests are  REST API.)

Comment: @DavidMaze What is the approach to microservice architecture for storing images? (When images are located in different services.)

Comment: Each microservice manages its own data and is isolated from other microservices.  You could make an argument for having a separate image-storage service with its own separate REST API (or using cloud-hosted storage like Amazon S3 for this purpose) but you generally want to avoid sharing files between services.

Comment: I wanted to use Amazon S3, but since I did not have the budget, I was looking for another solution to store the data on my server. Thanks @DavidMaze

Answer (score 2):

I using MinIO with Nginx on Docker.
Here is steps that I configure MinIO.

## Initial Config

### Step 1: Create minio user

Create `minio` user

```
sudo useradd minio
```

You then add a password for the `minio` user by using the `passwd` command:

```
sudo passwd minio
```

### Step 2: Create shared folder

Make minIO directory and change owner to `minio` user:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/minio
sudo chown -R minio:minio /usr/local/share/minio
```

## Docker

### Step 3: Create docker container:

Create docker container with:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

> This command create your `s3` container. Check it with `docker ps` command.

## Nginx

### Step 4: Create subdomain

Open `/etc/host` file and add your subdomain:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost 
127.0.0.1       s3.localhost # You can rename `s3` with desired name.
```

So at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` edit server_name key as `s3.localhost`.

```
...
// add this block at the end of `default` file:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name s3.localhost;

    index index.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
    }
}
```

Then restart nginx:

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

## Run MinIO ‍♂️

Go to your browser and open [s3.localhost](http://s3.localhost).

Username and password is in `.env` file. Login and create your `Buckets`.

### Check out [my repo](https://github.com/realsaeedhassani/MinIO-Nginx-Docker).